# Proving $2n-8<n^2-8n+14$ for all $n\geq 7$ by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

For what values of the natural number $n$ is $2n-8 < n^2-8n+14$? (must use induction)

I have determined that $n$ appears to work for all values except $n=4,5,6$.

I was wondering if this proof that I constructed is valid (for all intents and purposes of this post, I'm skipping the base cases).

**Induction Hypothesis** Suppose $2n-8 < n^2-8n+14$ is true for all $n\geq 7$.

To show that the proposition is true for the $n+1$th terms, we proceed as follows.

From the induction hypothesis we know

$2n-8 < n^2-8n+14$

Because $2n-6 < 2n-8$, we deduce from the transitive property that

$$2n-6 < n^2-8n+14\tag{1}$$

Because $-8n < -6n$, we have

$-8n < -6n < -6n+7$

$-8n < -6n+7 = -6n+14-7$

$-8n-14 < -6n-7$

Finally, we know that $-6n-7 < -6n+7$. Therefore,

$-8n-14 < -6n+7$

and

$$n^2-8n-14 < n^2-6n+7\tag{2}$$

Using the transitive property on $(1)$ and $(2)$, we conclude

$2n-6 < n^2-6n+7$,

which is the $n+1$th term, as desired.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  A friendly reminder, it helps a great deal for readers of your question if you properly format your mathematics.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial on how to type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax on this site.  Also, it helps to link to [related questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242126/mathematical-induction-on-a-subset-of-the-natural-numbers) when appropriate.

Comment: @ Benedict Be warned that a single linebreak isn't enough for MathJax to display things as separate lines here.  Many of your lines appear as one (e.g. -8n < -6n < -6n+7 -8n < -6n+7 =... instead of -8n < -6n < -6n+7 \newline -8n < -6n+7 =...)

Comment: Upon reading through your proof @Benedict it appears correct, though there are several lines where you specifically mention the transitivity of $<$ which makes this feel incredibly wordy.  It could be done in one or two lines if desired.  The other comment I have about it is that you began with "...is true **for all** n>=7."  This is not what you want to write.  Instead it should be written as "...is true **for some** $n\geq 7$"

Comment: Note $n^2-8n+14-(2n-8)=n^2-10n+22=(n-7)(n-3)+1>0$ for all $n\geq 7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really really* want a proof by induction, then I would prove it as follows:

For $n\geq 7$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : 2n-8 < n^2-8n+14.
$$
**Base case ($n=7$):** $S(7)$ says that $2(7)-8=6<7=7^2-8(7)+14$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 7$ and assume $S(k)$ to be true where
$$
S(k) : 2k-8 < k^2-8k+14.
$$
To be shown is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : 2(k+1)-8 < (k+1)^2-8(k+1)+14.
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$, 
\begin{align}
2(k+1)-8 &= (2k+2)-8\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&= (2k-8)+2\tag{rearrange}\\[0.5em]
&< (k^2-8k+14)+2\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
&< k^2-6k+7\tag{since $k\geq 7$}\\[0.5em]
&= (k+1)^2-8(k+1)+14,\tag{desired expression}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 7$. $\blacksquare$